# Is it suggested to read the "Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda"?

Tags: vedanta, vivekananda

Or should we read/refer/practice/ to the originally written literature and do not go beyond that with anything.

Background(in case): Complete beginner, I just started reading Bhagvad Geeta(2 days back).

Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda Link: https://advaitaashrama.org/cw/

Comment: Yes. I read it almost cover-to-cover a couple of times when I was a complete beginner just like you. Along with Ramakrishna Kathamrita.

Comment: Your question is inviting opinion based answers. It needs to be closed